# Vue Snapshot testing with RouterLinkStub does not render anchor as expected

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-router, snapshot, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to run jest-snapshot tests in a Vue application which has a Component with `router-link` element.
I'm using `RouterLinkStub` as recommended in [Snapshot Testing with Vue-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917129/snapshot-testing-with-vue-router)

My component template is something like

```
<template>
  <section class="content">
    <div>
      <router-link to="/" v-slot="{ href, route, navigate }">
        <a :href="href" @click="navigate">
          Homepage
        </a>
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

The problem is that in snapshot, the `router-link` renders as empty anchor element (`<a />`), so if I change the link text the snapshot test stills pass.

This is my snapshot test:

```
import { RouterLinkStub, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'

import PageNotFound from 'views/PageNotFound.vue'

describe('PageNotFound.vue', () => {
  it('renders as expected', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(PageNotFound, {
      stubs: {
        RouterLink: RouterLinkStub
      }
    })

    expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

Can you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: It seems there's an issue with RouterLinkStub and the new slot API, It is being tracked here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1803

Answer (score 0):

With Vue 3

```
 import { shallowMount, RouterLinkStub } from '@vue/test-utils'
 import router from '../../router'

 const findComponentRouterLink = () => 
   wrapper.findComponent(RouterLinkStub)

 const wrapper = shallowMount(Component, {
   global: {
        plugins: [router],
        stubs: {
          RouterLink: RouterLinkStub,
        },
      },
    })

 findComponentRouterLink().text()).toBe('Link text')
```